# How to filter through nested dictionaries in a list

Tags: python

I have a patient_list that contains nested dictionaries as below:
patient_list

```
[ {"id": 1
   "hospital":{"id": 1
    "doctor":{"id": 1}}
  },
  {"id": 2
   "hospital":{"id": 2
    "doctor":{"id": 1}}
  }]
```

I am trying to filter into it so that I can get all the patients that belong to the doctor of id=1. I have tried different variations of the following solution but I did not succeed.Am not sure if it is the correct approach.I will appreciate any help.

```
id=1
result = [d for d in patient_list['hospital']['doctor'] if d['id'] == id]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot index list with strings, it should be done on each list item.

```
idx = 1
results = [d for d in patient_list if d['hospital']['doctor']['id'] == idx]
```

this would translate into

```
idx = 1

results = []
for patient in patient_list:
    hospital = patient['hospital']
    doctor = hospital['doctor']
    doctor_id = doctor['id']
    if doctor_id == idx:
        results.append(patient)
```

Comment: This worked .Thanks! You can edit the answer you typed 'in' twice. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

The json is in the question is incorrect.

Assuming the json is as follows:

```
In [6]: patient_list
Out[6]:
[{'id': 1, 'hospital': {'id': 1}, 'doctor': {'id': 1}},
 {'id': 2, 'hospital': {'id': 2}, 'doctor': {'id': 1}}]

In [7]: [d for d in patient_list if d["doctor"]['id'] == id]
Out[7]:
[{'id': 1, 'hospital': {'id': 1}, 'doctor': {'id': 1}},
 {'id': 2, 'hospital': {'id': 2}, 'doctor': {'id': 1}}]
```

Comment: don't overwrite the built-in `id` with the variable, use `_id` or `id_` instead

Comment: Good point @gold_cy. The code will still work